# Wordpress: get author link outside the Loop?

Tags: wordpress

I want author page link outside the Loop? Please anybody tell me Wordpress functions?

Comment: Try rephrasing your question and show us what you've researched so far.

Comment: For a specific post or something else? (Ie. author of what?)

Answer (score 4):

Use the function:

```
get_author_posts_url($author_id);
```

([Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url).)

Comment: ok thanks I have used the same function display author page Link outside the Loop Using Post Auhtor-Id .I have used below get_author_posts_url( $contest->post_author);

Answer (score 2):

Use `get_author_posts_url()` function to get the author link outside of loop.

```
global $post;
$author_id=$post->post_author;

echo get_author_posts_url($author_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting a link to a specific author page, you can use **yourwebsite.com/?author=23** (this would be a link to author number 23).

You can find the author number by looking in the wordpress backend, under **users > all users**, then hovering over the one you're wanting to link to.